# Ruby make http get request with base64 header

Tags: ruby, http-headers

How would I try to make an http request with a authorized header?
I am trying to make a http request but I need to have this included in the header `"Basic" + Base64::strict_encode64("example@email.com:34infds88ae23fdsfasd3241c930e")`

The error I am getting from running the code below is  `Failed to open TCP connection to www.exampleWebsite.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) (SocketError)`

I am currently trying

```
uri = URI.parse("https://www.example.website.com/api/v2/users")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
request.basic_auth("example@email.com", "34infds88ae23fdsfasd3241c930e")
response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack Overflow :)

From what I can see, the way you're doing the basic authentication looks good. As [the docs state](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Basic+Authentication), the `#basic_auth` method follows the [RFC2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) which takes care of the Base64 encoding.

But I think the issue might be that if you're trying to request an `HTTPS` page (not just `HTTP`), you'll have to manually enable it to use SSL. You can do this by setting the `use_ssl` flag to `true` on your `Net::HTTP` instance like so:

```rb
uri = URI.parse("https://www.example.website.com/api/v2/users")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.use_ssl = true # <- this

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
request.basic_auth("example@email.com", "34infds88ae23fdsfasd3241c930e")
response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

When using the `Net::HTTP.get(uri)` shortcut, the library automatically recognizes that the `uri` is for an SSL-protected site and switches the `use_ssl` flag on. But this doesn't work when needing to set additional headers on the request, like the basic authentication. In that case, we have to manually turn the flag on.

To test this, I used [this W3 Jigsaw demo page](https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Basic/) `https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Basic/` that's Basic-Auth protected with user: `guest` / pw: `guest` and the request then seemed to work.